# Named Routes Not Used In Certain Conditions? - AbstractController::ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form that uses jQuery autocomplete to return a list of client names. For the autocomplete function the source is set to a named route.

```
            $( "#clientfinder" ).autocomplete({
                source: 'findclients',
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 600,
                select: function(event,ui){
                      $('#clientfinder_id').val(ui.item.id)
                        }
                });

            -- routes

            match 'findclients' => 'contact#find_clients'
```

The autocomplete source using the route works fine as long as the form field is used for updating a record, but not for creating a new record. The create and update views both use the same partial _form.html.erb, and therefore the same field with the same id. But when the form is used to create a record I get:

Started GET "/search_log/findclients?term=fid" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-07 11:45:59 -0500
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'findclients' could not be found for SearchLogController):

Once the record is created and I'm using the form for updating the record I get:

Started GET "/findclients?term=fid" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-07 11:46:56 -0500
  Processing by ContactController#find_clients as JSON

It's like if the form partial is use for creation, the named route is ignored and the current controller is called. But if the form is used for updating a record, the named route is used. I don't see how the rails framework knows the difference.

Am I missing something here?